# How to redirect to root page in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm now redirecting to main page in my Rails application using

```
redirect_to root_path
```

I want to do the same in jQuery.

i.e. `window.location.replace("???");`

How to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`window.location = '/'`

Disadvantage in using `window.location.replace('/')` is user won't be able to press "Back" and go back to the previous page.